# Deregistering and registering javascript breaks plugin

Tags: plugins

While you can view the [full file here](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/basic-comment-quicktags/tags/1.6/quicktags.php), here's the function that enqueues the JavaScript file(s) needed by the plugin:

```
function ippy_bcq_add_scripts() {

$options = get_option('ippy_bcq_options');
$valuebb = $options['bbpress'];
$valueco = $options['comments'];
$ippy_bcq_bbp_fancy = get_option( '_bbp_use_wp_editor' );

  if ( function_exists('is_bbpress') ) {
          if ( is_bbpress()  && ( $valuebb != '0') && !is_null($valuebb) && ($ippy_bcq_bbp_fancy == '0') ) {
            wp_enqueue_script("bcq_quicktags", plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . "quicktags.js", array("quicktags","jquery"), "1.8", 1);
            wp_enqueue_style("bcq_quicktags", plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . "quicktags.css", false, "1.8");
            wp_print_styles('editor-buttons');
        }
  }
  if ( comments_open() && is_singular() && ( $valueco != '0') && !is_null($valueco) ) {
                    wp_enqueue_script("bcq_quicktags", plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . "quicktags.js", array("quicktags","jquery"), "1.8", 1);
                    wp_enqueue_style("bcq_quicktags", plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . "quicktags.css", false, "1.8");
                    wp_print_styles('editor-buttons');
  }
}

if( !is_admin() ) {
    add_action('wp_print_styles', 'ippy_bcq_add_scripts');
}
```

Now, as you can see, `quicktags` ($handle) is one of the dependencies (alongside jQuery) required the JavaScript enqueued by the plugin.

`quicktags` represents this file: `http://example.com/wp-includes/js/quicktags.js`, and I need to have the file served from a different domain, like this for instance — `http://static-domain.com/wp-includes/js/quicktags.js`. How do I do it?

I tried these two in my theme's functions.php, but they seem to break the JavaScript output by the plugin for some reason:

- **TRY - 1:**

  ```
  add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','aahan_register_script');
  function aahan_register_script(){

      wp_deregister_script('quicktags');
      wp_register_script('quicktags', 'http://static-domain.com/wp-includes/js/quicktags.js', false, false, true);
      wp_enqueue_script( 'quicktags' );

  }
  ```
- **TRY - 2:**

  ```
  add_action('wp_print_styles','aahan_register_script');
  function aahan_register_script(){

      wp_deregister_script('quicktags');
      wp_register_script('quicktags', 'http://static-domain.com/wp-includes/js/quicktags.js', false, false, true);
      wp_enqueue_script( 'quicktags' );

  }
  ```

I also did try a few other variants, but none worked. What am I doing wrong?

---

### More Info

By default the plugin outputs code like this in the footer:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var quicktagsL10n = {"wordLookup":"Enter a word to look up:","dictionaryLookup":"Dictionary lookup","lookup":"lookup","closeAllOpenTags":"Close all open tags","closeTags":"close tags","enterURL":"Enter the URL","enterImageURL":"Enter the URL of the image","enterImageDescription":"Enter a description of the image","fullscreen":"fullscreen","toggleFullscreen":"Toggle fullscreen mode","textdirection":"text direction","toggleTextdirection":"Toggle Editor Text Direction"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/wp-includes/js/quicktags.js?ver=3.4.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://static-domain.com/wp-content/plugins/basic-comment-quicktags/quicktags.js?ver=1.8'></script>
```

But when I try the aforementioned functions, the output code is this (essentially broken):

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://whatthenerd.com/wp-includes/js/quicktags.js?ver=3.4.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://wtn-static.whatthenerd.net/wp-content/plugins/basic-comment-quicktags/quicktags.js?ver=1.8'></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, got it to work. Add this in functions.php:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','aahank_register_script');
function aahank_register_script(){

//Re-register quicktags script
wp_deregister_script('quicktags');
wp_register_script('quicktags', 'http://static-content.com/wp-includes/js/quicktags.js', false, false, true);
wp_localize_script( 'quicktags', 'quicktagsL10n', array(
    'wordLookup' => __('Enter a word to look up:'),
    'dictionaryLookup' => esc_attr(__('Dictionary lookup')),
    'lookup' => esc_attr(__('lookup')),
    'closeAllOpenTags' => esc_attr(__('Close all open tags')),
    'closeTags' => esc_attr(__('close tags')),
    'enterURL' => __('Enter the URL'),
    'enterImageURL' => __('Enter the URL of the image'),
    'enterImageDescription' => __('Enter a description of the image'),
    'fullscreen' => __('fullscreen'),
    'toggleFullscreen' => esc_attr( __('Toggle fullscreen mode') ),
    'textdirection' => esc_attr( __('text direction') ),
    'toggleTextdirection' => esc_attr( __('Toggle Editor Text Direction') )
));

}
```

As for the code used in `wp_localize_script`, I got it straight from source: http://core.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/wp-includes/media.php

Comment: Cross-posted from: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/844266